# Unable to write to file - why?

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to save to long term file storage in android as well as create a new file in the process. This code keeps crashing with minimal helpful logcat.

Thanks.

```
public void save (String text) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput("logfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(text.getBytes());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(fos != null)
        {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to create a file called logfile.txt and print text to it but instead it crashes.

Comment: Part of the reason your Logcat isn't giving you anything useful is because you are suppressing the `FileNotFoundException` - print the stacktrace inside that catch block in the same you have for `IOException`

Comment: @AngelKoh: The OP is using `openFileOutput()`. That takes a filename, not a path, and writes the content to the location identified by `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, you are right.

Comment: Somehow with that change the program no longer crashes, but the intended result still does not occur with the method call save("Sample text"). Does anyone know where the default file would be stored with this code? under STORAGE/Android/data/com.[NAME OF PROGRAM]?

Answer (score 0):

Try something alike this, in order to get a `FileOutputStream` from a `File` in tmp / private storage:

```
// File file = File.createTempFile("logfile", ".txt");
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "logfile.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

The resulting path should be `/data/data/tld.domain.package/files/logfile.txt`.

`file.getAbsolutePath()` has the value.

See [Save a file on internal storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/internal).